# How to share a netbeans-project via SVN

Tags: android, svn, ide, netbeans-7

I'm currently trying to get a grip on SVN and how to handle projects in them. We have several IDE's and types of projects, so, I'd like to just pick one:
Sharing a Netbeans-project for Android, I'd like to know, if there's a way not to stupidly commit everything, but only those files, that are coded and/or really necessary for a project to be recognized and run as such, so that an 'open project' would work in a checked out working copy?

Thanx for any pointers!
Regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question relates to dealing with SVN via an external tool, in my case, we use Versions. As I specifically asked for Netbeans, there is a workaround. Netbeans provides an integrated, simple SCN-client and greatly enough, it figures out which files to share on it's own.
So, that obviously doesn't apply to other IDEs, but at least for the one in question here, it does it's job.